# Call controller with parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to call a controller in an other controller with a parameter. I have no problem without any parameters.

```
return app()->call('App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController@create');
```

AppointmentController.php

```
class AppointmentController extends Controller
{

    public function create(CalendarInterface $calendar, Request $request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I have an error when I try to pass one.

```
return app()->call('App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController@create', $response);
```

AppointmentController.php

```
class AppointmentController extends Controller
{

    public function create($response, CalendarInterface $calendar, Request $request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Container\Container::call() must be of the type array, object given

Or if I do

```
return app()->call('App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController@create', [$response]);
```

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController::create() must implement interface App\CalendarInterface, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given in [...]/app/Http/Controllers/AppointmentController.php:18

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You need to do `app()->call('App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController@create', [ $response ]);`

Comment: I have already tried that. `Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController::create() must implement interface App\CalendarInterface, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given in [...]/app/Http/Controllers/AppointmentController.php:18
`

Comment: Why do you want to call a controller in the first place? This is not recommended. You should refactor your code

Comment: I'm building a bot, when the bot receive a message, it calls a controller. The bot can do many things, so I have a controller for every thing.

Comment: use events and listners for example !!

Comment: I find that events and listeners make the code hard to follow.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Use named parameters:

```
app()->call('App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController@create',  [
    "response" => $response
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel's automagic DI probably doesn't support this use case, passing only parts of the arguments and asking him to guess what remains to be resolved.

Try passing all the arguments:

```
app()->call(
    'App\Http\Controllers\AppointmentController@create',
    [$response, app(CalendarInterface::class), app(Request::class)]
);
```

As a side note, calling such a "sub-controller" is probably a bad practice. How about moving the business logic to plain classes?